# Unable to access React Application from Minikube

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I've a simple HelloWorld ReactJs application Docker image and I created the deployment as:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: minikube-react-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minikube-react-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: minikube-react-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: minikube-react-app
          image: hello-react:1.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "100Mi"
              cpu: "300m"
            limits:
              memory: "200Mi"
              cpu: "600m"
      restartPolicy: Always
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: minikube-react-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31000
  selector:
    app: minikube-react-app
```

I ran, kubectl apply -f deployent.yaml

But when I access http://localhost:31000 it's not working(This site can’t be reached).

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Does your image contain a Create React App dev server, or a  server that serves a React project's built files?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command to get the actual address to connect with your app from host machine.

```
minikube service --url <service-name>
```

Ref: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/

Comment: I was unable to reach `<minikub-ip>:port` on M1. Using your solution it did work as it showed the following warning which made sense:
`Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.`
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should use 'node ip' instead of 'localhost' to acccess node port.

Run shell `minikube ip` to obtain ip of minikube node.

Check the service type: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types